# Secure Store Service Certificate Issue Event ID 7557

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, wcf, secure-store

I have recently created Secure Store Service in my Production environment. Its never been up since its creation and i am seeing a generic error below when navigating to service. However its working fine on Dev and UAT environments.

[image]

I have checked the logs but could not find any resolution yet. Below are the logs details.

> The Secure Store Service application Secure Store Service is not
>   accessible. The full exception text is: An error occurred while making
>   the HTTP request to
>   https://SERVER:32844/0bcdc6cacc6b4aeca8f6686649c722ce/SecureStoreService.svc/https.
>   This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not
>   configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also
>   be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and
>   the server.

and

```
Logging unknown/unexpected client side exception: CommunicationException. This will cause this application server to be removed from the load balancer queue. Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://SERVER:32844/0bcdc6cacc6b4aeca8f6686649c722ce/SecureStoreService.svc/https. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host    
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    
 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)    
 at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    
 at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    
 at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    
 at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)    
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    
 at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)    
 at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)    
 at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)    
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:     
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown
 at [0]:     
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)    
 at Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.ISecureStoreServiceApplication.IsMasterSecretKeyPopulated()    
 at Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.<IsMasterSecretKeyPopulated>b__5c(ISecureStoreServiceApplication serviceApplication)    
 at Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.Execute[T](String operationName, Boolean validateCanary, ExecuteDelegate`1 operation).
```

and the last one below.

```
Error occured while managing Secure Store Application ccf7e37a-246e-41e0-be40-801071d973cc. Error message: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Secure Store Service did not performed the operation.    
 at Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.Execute[T](String operationName, Boolean validateCanary, ExecuteDelegate`1 operation)    
 at Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.IsMasterSecretKeyPopulated()    
 at Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions.SecureStoreAdministration.SSSAdminHelper.EnsurePrerequisite(SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy proxy, String& errorMessage)    
 at Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions.SecureStoreAdministration.ManageSSSvcApplication.InitializeGridView().
```

It looks like more related to WCF service issue to me. However till now i am unable to find any clue. I have checked the permissions for the Secure Store Service account in SharePoint CA and on DB server too. Everything is as expected. Please help.

Comment: I've had issues where antivirus and endpoint protections were blocking secure store, Office Web Apps, and the security token service. Are you sure it's not related to that?

Answer (score 0):

This error tells me Secure Store Service is not started. Could you please do this.

- Log on Central admin > System Settings > Manage Services on server
- On this page, Please make Sure Secure store Service is started. if not start it.
- One more thing, If you have more than one server in the farm please make sure SSS service is started on at least 2 servers.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468696(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I have two application servers and its started on both servers.

Comment: ok, try to stop and start it. also try to recycle the App pool of SSS on the both servers

Comment: Already stopped and started along with Claims to Windows Token Service and PerformancePoint Service (I have read about these to restart somewhere). In addition, i have recycled application pools, IISRESET and rebooted servers but yet no luck.

Comment: what shows in the browser when you browse this https://SERVER:32844/0bcdc6cacc6b4aeca8f6686649c722ce/SecureStoreService.svc

Comment: Also make sure ports are not blocked TCP/32844 this is for sss.

Comment: When i browse the above URL, i see the generic WCF service page. I believe that port is open in firewall.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check IIS SharePoint Web Service Start

Comment: It is started...